# Is it possible to copy files from one computer (which is remotely accessing another one through terminal) to the other one?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, remote-access, file-copying

I'm using a Mac to remotely access a computer in my university's computer lab. The Mac serves as a terminal. If I need to transfer some files from my computer into the one in the lab, is it, firstly, possible? If yes, then please guide me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, use the UNIX / Linux command scp (secure copy):

```
$ scp user@server:directory/SourceFile TargetFile
```

**Update based on OP's response:**

```
$ scp path/to/my/file.txt user@server.com:/path/to/copy/to/file.txt
```

Comment: scp user@server:users/name/desktop/xyz/file.txt file.txt.

please correct if this is wrong.

Comment: Looks right to me. Just to clarify, 'users/name/desktop/xyz/file.txt' is the path to the file on the remote host that you wish to copy. The file will be copied to whichever directory you were in when you ran scp and it will be called 'file.txt'

Comment: actually i wish to copy a file 'to' the remote host. or you could say i want to send a file to the one i'm remotely controlling.